# How to save a custom form image to a custom user field

Tags: image, forms, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-forms

I have a custom form that creates a new user and fills in a number of custom fields for that user. One of these fields is a custom image (not the system avatar image).

I can get the image uploaded to the server through the form, but can't get it into the appropriate field. Here is my (custom module) code so-far.

```
function newacc_freebusiness_form($form, &$form_state) { 

$form['bussimage'] = array(
  '#title' => t('Upload an image that shows off your business.'),
  '#type' => 'managed_file',
  '#description' => t('Max size of 3Mb and filetype of jpg jpeg or png'),
  '#upload_location' => 'public://bussimages/',
  '#upload_validators' => array(
    'file_validate_extensions' => array('png jpg jpeg'),
    'file_validate_size' => array(3*1024*1024),
      ),
  '#required' => TRUE,
);
 $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => 'Submit',
 );

 $form['#validate'][] = 'newacc_freebusiness_validate';

 return $form;
 }
 function newacc_freebusiness_validate($form, &$form_state) {
  $bussimage = $form_state['values']['bussimage'];
  $file = file_load($bussimage);
  $bussimage = image_load($file -> uri);
  image_save($bussimage);
  $bussimage = image_load($file -> uri);
  $edit = array(
    'name' => 'name',
    'mail' => 'mail@mail.com',
    'status' => 0,
    'language' => 'en',
    'init' => 'mail@mail.com',
    'roles' => array(8 => 'Promoter'),
    'field_business_image' => array(        
    'und' => array(
        0 => array(
            'value' => $bussimage,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        );
        user_save(NULL, $edit);
 }
```

This is throwing the error message:

```
Notice: Undefined index: fid in file_field_presave() (line 219 of /var/www/drupal_site/modules/file/file.field.inc).
```

I have tried so many tricks now and googled so long that I can't even explain what I have and haven't tried anymore!

Any help please.

Comment: managed_file gets saved to database after submission -isn't it ? So you can't expect file object's values in validation function.

Comment: No, managed file is saved and stored in database before form validation in seperate upload validation. Image_load() is returning a valid image object with fid included. I just cant get user_save() to store it into my field.

Comment: This is my first question on SO and somebody deemed it necessary to mark it down? I thought it was very clear, researched and helpful. Anyway - live and learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK - solved this. The clue was in the error message and the solution was very simple! Here is the code:

```
function newacc_freebusiness_form($form, &$form_state) { 

    $form['bussimage'] = array(
    '#title' => t('Upload an image that shows off your business.'),
    '#type' => 'managed_file',
    '#description' => t('Max size of 3Mb and filetype of jpg jpeg or png'),
    '#upload_location' => 'public://bussimages/',
    '#upload_validators' => array(
    'file_validate_extensions' => array('png jpg jpeg'),
    'file_validate_size' => array(3*1024*1024),
    ),
    '#required' => TRUE,
    );
$form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => 'Submit',
);

$form['#validate'][] = 'newacc_freebusiness_validate';

return $form;
}
function newacc_freebusiness_validate($form, &$form_state) {
    $bussimage = $form_state['values']['bussimage'];
    $file = file_load($bussimage);
    $edit = array(
    'name' => 'name',
    'mail' => 'mail@mail.com',
    'status' => 0,
    'language' => 'en',
    'init' => 'mail@mail.com',
    'roles' => array(8 => 'Promoter'),
    'field_business_image' => array(        
        'und' => array(
            0 => array(
            'fid' => $file -> fid,
        ),
      ),
    ),
    );
user_save(NULL, $edit);
}
```

All Drupal was looking for was the file fid in the array. Don't know why I initially assumed it had to be more complicated than this.